# Django report builder TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS and Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, report

I'm following django report builder quick start manual:

1. pip install django-report-builder - DONE
2. Add report_builder to INSTALLED_APPS - DONE
3. Add url(r'^report_builder/', include('report_builder.urls')) to
   url.py url patterns - DONE
4. Ensure django.core.context_processors.static and
   django.core.context_processors.media are in
   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS - NOT DONE. The Django doc says these options are changed in Django 1.8 and I failed to find where and how do I ensure that.
5. Sync your database. python manage.py migrate - DONE.
6. Use Django admin or navigate to /report_builder/ - DONE. The page is just loading endlessly.

It looks like the issue is with step #4. How do I set up the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS for django reports builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context processors go in the `OPTIONS` dictionary in the `TEMPLATES` setting.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        OPTIONS = {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                # add your template context processor here
            ],
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
]
```

The `media` and `static` context processors that you need should be included by default, so you shouldn't have to make any changes.

See the docs on upgrading templates to [Django 1.8 for more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/#upgrading-templates-to-django-1-8).

Comment: Great! Maybe you could open an issue for django-report-builder or write  a patch to update the docs for 1.8.